# Good tutorial for RESTful Services

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

can anyone post a good tutorial or sample for WCF RESTful services/I want to learn from the basic.

Comment: Look for the excellent Aron Skonard videos from pluralsight on this subject.

Comment: @neil - that's not a very constructive comment.

Comment: Google has a million and one resources not all of them good, don't see anything wrong with someone asking for a bit of direction and help.

Answer (score 6):

A good book for [RESTful Web Services](http://tinoweb.googlecode.com/files/O%27Reilly%20-RESTful.Web.Services.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [step-by-step guide from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have great [Labs](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfrestlabs/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2368) tutorials for REST.

Once i did those i found i could understand more content from [REST Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) papers.